# Multidimensional Array Of Signals in VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I have a signal in VHDL declared like this :

```
signal Temp_Key : std_logic_vector(79 downto 0);
```

This `Temp_Key` is passed through a `for` loop 31 times and it is modified. I want to store all the 31 different `Temp_Keys` in an array.

Is it possible to use multi-dimensional arrays in VHDL to store 80 bit signals ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, first you need to declare a type:

```
type YOUR_ARRAY_TYPE is array (0 to 30) of std_logic_vector(79 downto 0);
```

Note you can also declare the type to be of undefined length - so you can specify how many 80 bit words it has when you declare your signal. And with VHDL 2008, you can also leave the size of the slv unspecified, also to be declared when you create your signal. For example:

```
type slv_array is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
```

and then use it

```
signal MY_SIGNAL : YOUR_ARRAY_TYPE;
...
MY_SIGNAL(0) <= data;
...
MY_SIGNAL(1) <= data;
```

See [here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese171/vhdl/vhdl_primer.html#_Toc526061356) for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Like the post above says, you can create any multi-dimensional array datatype.
The other thing you need to be careful about is whether this code is synthesizable (i.e. targeted to FPGAs or ASICs, or is it purely for simulation). You can iterate from 0 to 31 using an FSM/counter or a generate block depending on how critical your timing is and how much area you are willing to use. A multi-dimensional array instance shown in above post is certainly synthesizable.

Comment: Unfortunately the post above doesn't contain a multi-dimensional array type.  "An array object is characterized by the number of indices (the dimensionality of the array); ...", IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1.  The shown array type has only one index. The element type happens to be an array type.

Answer (score 0):

In VHDL there are two options

### Option 1

```
signal X is array (range) of ArrayType;
```

### Option 2

```
signal Y is array (range1, range2) of Type;
```

I think that option 1 is better supported by the tools. I also find similarity between these two options and the functional programming that teaches us that we can always [curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) a multivariate function (x,y) into a chain of single parameter ones, f(x) -> f(y). The latter looks like *array of arrays*.

Comment: So when using Option 2 and passing this signal to a function, how could I get the range1 and range2 again?

Comment: Do you mean that it will be a problem to store 80 bit signals in 31 different Temp_Keys? How is it related with the question and my answer. It does not seem easy to iterate arbitrary 2D-array. It is a good question actually. Much better than asking for 2d-array syntax. That is why you ask it to me rather than stackoverflow.